# Изменение скрипта до загрузки в браузер

Tags: delphi

Нужно написать программу, которая будет менять скрипт до загрузки в браузер (IE).
Если есть готовые заготовки, буду рад.

Comment: А готовую можете написать чтоб просто поменять мне скрип который надо на который надо?

Answer (score 1):

По идее надо [вызвать метод](http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.com/2009/02/javascript-twebbrowser-delphi.html) ExecScript для объекта типа IHTMLWindow2. Для работы с JavaScript из Delphi вы можете использовать TWEBbrowser, в том числе этот модифицированный вариант: [jsWebrowser](http://jqbook.narod.ru/works/jsWebBrowser.htm).